# Bing "Address Object" is missing adminDistrict or postalCode

Tags: javascript, bing, bing-api, bing-maps

I'm using Bing's [Autosuggest UI(Without Map)](http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#autoSuggestUiWithoutMap) to populate an autocomplete in an address input, but depending on the query, the `selectedResult` is missing either an `adminDistrict` or a `postalCode`.

The code below is very similar to the one used on Bing's [demo](http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#autoSuggestUiWithoutMap+TS). The only difference is in the `innerHTML` of `selectedSuggestion()`.

Two examples of addresses for which information is missing are the following:

1) 242 W 16th St, New York, NY **- missing adminDistrict**;
2) 227 W Trade St, Charlotte, NC **- missing zipCode**.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue, so that every `selectedResult` contains an `adminDistrict` and a `zipCode`?

```
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.AutoSuggest', {
  callback: onLoad,
  errorCallback: onError,
  credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key'
}); 

function onLoad() {
  var options = {maxResults: 5}; 
  var manager = new Microsoft.Maps.AutosuggestManager(options);
  manager.attachAutosuggest('#searchBox', '#searchBoxContainer', selectedSuggestion);
}

function onError(message) {
  document.getElementById('printoutPanel').innerHTML = message;
}


function selectedSuggestion(suggestionResult) {
  document.getElementById('printoutPanel').innerHTML =
    'Suggestion: ' + suggestionResult.formattedSuggestion +
    '<br> Street: ' + suggestionResult.address.addressLine + 
    '<br> City: ' + suggestionResult.address.locality + 
    '<br> State: ' + suggestionResult.address.adminDistrict + 
    '<br> Zip: ' + suggestionResult.address.postalCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autosuggest is meant to aid with geocoding results. The primary goal of geocoding is to find the coordinate for displaying an address in the right location on a map. Anything else is extra and not guaranteed to be returned. A geocoder is not an address validation tool.

That said, I'm a bit surprised that the adminDistrict isn't returned. Not returning a zip code could be for a large number of reason.

Comment: Thanks, @rbrundritt, for the explanation. Does Bing have a tool that would  validate the address?

Comment: No. true address validation services are only really available in a small number of countries are usually fairly expensive. May companies often use geocoders as a cheap alternative, but it isn't 100% perfect.